# Create browser session on Windows/IIS/ASP and import it into RHEL/Apache/Perl

Tags: perl, session, import, asp-classic, cross-domain

I have this configuration: Server1 running IIS and ASP and Server2 running RHEL and Perl.

I'd like to create a browser session from ASP and then import that into the other server via Perl, is that possible?

thank you in advance!
e.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and 2 ways right now to think of this.

First way is to use `Cookies` instead of `Session`, and in the cookie, make sure you have a way for both your applications to read off the same cookie.

Second way, do a `HTTPRequest` or `cURL` to an internal script on the other server that sync's your applications sessions, on login or whatever.

Comment: Hi Zee Tee! Thank you for your answer... 

Here's the deal... for your first option: can I set a cookie to be cross-domain? I'm not really sure about it. Option two: if I understood correctly you're saying to connect from destination server to the original server and grab a list of users currently logged in from there? something like a webservice? I believe it would be hard to match the users on server1 and server2 due to firewalls that could turn the IPs difficult to find when trying to match by IP (as this is the only way I can imagine to check the access as per your method)

Thanks!
e.

Comment: To answer your first question, No. However, they can be on different subdomains.  And your second, Yes, a web-service of some sort that can be restricted via IP, Basic Authentication, or any homemade auth solution.